# Update table with constrained values from another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm fairly new to SQL and tried solving this problem for about two days now, to no avail.

The question is, how can I update values in table Table_1 from values in Table_2, considering only specific subset of rows in Table_2, and without using cursors if possible.

More specifically, I have these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LastAmount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LastDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY];

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_2](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Amount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Date_] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY];
```

In the tables there are following values:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1]
    VALUES (1, 0, CONVERT(DATETIME, '19000101', 112)),
           (2, 0, CONVERT(DATETIME, '19000101', 112));

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_2]
    VALUES (1, 10, CONVERT(DATETIME, '19750101', 112)),
           (1, 20, CONVERT(DATETIME, '19500101', 112)),
           (1, 15, CONVERT(DATETIME, '20000101', 112)),
           (2, 30, CONVERT(DATETIME, '20100101', 112));
```

The point is to update values in Table_1 where ID matches Table_2.
Table_1.LastAmount should get Table_2.Amount with the most recent Table_2.Date_. Similarly for Table_1.LastDate it should get Table_2.Date_ where the date is the most recent for that specific ID.

So, Table_1 before update:

```
ID  |LastAmount |LastDate
----|-----------|--------
1   |0          |1900-01-01 00:00:00.0000
2   |0          |1900-01-01 00:00:00.0000
```

Table_2:

```
ID  |Amount     |Date
----|-----------|--------
1   |10         |1975-01-01 00:00:00.0000
1   |20         |1950-01-01 00:00:00.0000
1   |15         |2000-01-01 00:00:00.0000
2   |30         |2010-01-01 00:00:00.0000
```

Table_1 after update:

```
ID  |LastAmount |LastDate
----|-----------|--------
1   |15         |2000-01-01 00:00:00.0000
2   |30         |2010-01-01 00:00:00.0000
```

I tried all kinds of UPDATE with INNER JOIN, or using an inline SELECT when assigning the value, but none of them worked. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking about a TRIGGER solution?

Comment: Thanks for providing runnable sample data and expected results. It's a bit of a novelty :-)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever agree, without the scripts I probably wouldn't have bothered, so this was nice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `update from` is useful in this situation. `row_number()` is used here with the source table to determine the most recent entry in `Table_2`.

```
update
    Table_1
set
    LastAmount = T2.Amount
    ,LastDate = T2.Date_
from
    (
        select
            ID
            ,Amount
            ,Date_
            ,row_number() over (partition by ID order by Date_ desc) as RowNumber
        from
            Table_2
    ) T2
where
    Table_1.ID = T2.ID
    and T2.RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: All of the answers give correct results, however this one (using partition) seems the most clear for me. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
Update Table_1
Set LastAmount = Table_2.Amount,
LastDate = Table_2.[Date_]
from (SELECT ID, MAX([Date_]) as MaxDate FROM TABLE_2 GROUP BY ID) AS Max_Table2
inner join Table_2 on Max_Table2.MaxDate = Table_2.[Date_] and Max_Table2.id = Table_2.id
inner join table_1 on table_1.id = Table_2.id
```

Basically you have filter the table2 to get the max date and join everything up to find the lastdate and amount.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple use of [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) and a CTE to do this:

```
;With Ordered as (
    select ID,Amount,Date_,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date_ DESC) rn
    from Table_2
)
update t1
set LastAmount = o.Amount,
LastDate = o.Date_
from
  Table_1 t1
    inner join
  Ordered o
    on
      t1.ID = o.ID and
      o.rn = 1
```

(You could write it as a subquery rather than a CTE, but I picked a CTE in this example)